# test() function in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to test two strings using single regular expression (OR using single patter).

```
var reg_expr = (/(\d{1,2}?h$)|(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+))/gi)
str1 = "5h"
str2 = "7h"

if (reg_expr.test(str1) == true && reg_expr.test(str2) == true)
{ console.log("Matched.........") }
```

but gives `reg_expr.test(str1) --> true`
and       `reg_expr.test(str2) --> false`

Comment: Have you tried removing the global `g` flag?

Comment: Why is there a `$` in the regex?

Comment: $ is add for get h at end of the string like in meeting at 7h.

Comment: Why don't you use `/(\d{1,2}h)/i` instead?

Comment: because i have very complex regular expression this regular expression is for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove global switch otherwise [regex object maintains its state of `lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) so the next subsequent matches will start from the last used index in the input, instead of `0`.

```
var reg_expr = /(\d{1,2}?h$)|(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+))/i;

console.log(reg_expr.test(str1), reg_expr.test(str2));    
true true
```

Comment: but what is the reason , 'g' flag is remove than it works fine ????

Comment: Without `g` flag it doesn't remember `lastIndex`. Check the link I provided which says: **This property is set only if the regular expression used the `"g"` flag to indicate a global search**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse that reg_expr object.

```js
var reg_expr = (/(\d{1,2}?h$)|(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+))/gi);
str1 = "5h";

if (reg_expr.test(str1))
  window.alert("Matched >"+str1+"<");
else
  window.alert("Not Matched >"+str1+"<");

reg_expr = (/(\d{1,2}?h$)|(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+))/gi);
str2 = "7h";

if (reg_expr.test(str2))
  window.alert("Matched >"+str2+"<");
else
  window.alert("Not Matched >"+str2+"<");
```

---

edit: @anubhava is right - removing the "g" flag also works:

```js
var reg_expr = (/(\d{1,2}?h$)|(\d{1,2}h(?=\s+))/i);
str1 = "5h";

if (reg_expr.test(str1))
  window.alert("Matched >"+str1+"<");
else
  window.alert("Not Matched >"+str1+"<");

str2 = "7h";

if (reg_expr.test(str2))
  window.alert("Matched >"+str2+"<");
else
  window.alert("Not Matched >"+str2+"<");
```